# How can I add an item of an object to an object of a useState array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm receiving data like this:

```
user:
[
 {
   name: "John",
   city: "London",
   age: "21",
   language: "Enlgish"
 }
]
```

How can I put the value `language` in an object inside of a use state array?
My code by far:

```
const [language, setLanguage] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get('api')
    .then((response) => {
      response.data.user.map((user) => {
        setLanguage([{...user,  added:user.language)]
      })
    )
}, [])
```

I know this is wrong but what I want as a result is:

```
language: [
  {
    added: "English"
  }
]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: `[...language,{added:user.language)]`

Comment: Instead of iterating over the users array and setting the state for each iterated object you should create a new array of objects first, and then set the state _once_ with that new data.

Comment: Ignore my previous answer, I had misread the question.

Comment: What is the purpose of the received data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forEach` instead of map and slightly change the code

```
useEffect(() => {
axios
  .get('api').then((response) => {
    response.data.user.forEach((u) => setLanguage([...language, { added: u.language }]))
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to map the response and set the total combined array to the state once instead of setting the state for each element:

```js
const [language, setLanguage] = useState([]);
    
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('api')
       .then(response =>
           setLanguage(language => ([
                ...language, 
                ...response.data.user.map(({ language }) => ({ added: language }))
           ]))
}), []);
```